# How to change WKWebView text color?

Tags: html, css, ios, swift, wkwebview

I have a `ViewController` with `WKWebView` and I load my `.html` and `.css` files with text for `webView`. It is look like controller to reading books in Apple Books app.

```
do {
            guard let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "index", ofType: "html") 
                else {
                    print ("File reading error")
                    return
            }
            
            let headerString = "<meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"initial-scale=1.1\" />"
            let content =  try String(contentsOfFile: filePath, encoding: .utf8)
            let baseUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: filePath)
            
            webView.loadHTMLString(headerString+content, baseURL: baseUrl)

        }
        catch {
            print ("File HTML error")
        }
```

Also I have 4 themes to change appearance in my `ViewController`(white, black, navy and yellow, like in Apple Books). I want to change my text color in `webView` when I change theme. How to do it? How to change color of `webView`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your .html file you need to write JavaScript function (as example: *changeColor*) which changes color for your HTML elements. When you change theme in your ViewController you need to execute **callAsyncJavaScript** function with JavaScript function name.

```
let web = WKWebView()
web.callAsyncJavaScript("javaScriptFumction", in: WKContentWorld)
```

WKWebView have async implementation for **callAsyncJavaScript** function.

Comment: I have some error - https://ibb.co/ctVWfH8. But it is solution for iOS 14... What about supporting iOS 12,13?

Comment: UIWebView have similar functionality as well. You can consider swapping to this UI Element.

Comment: Ok... But I want to use WKWebView and my iOS deployment target 12